# jQuery toggle and toggling :checked

Tags: jquery

I have an input box which is hidden and I am using a span element to change the state of the checkbox but I can't quite figure out how to do it by toggling checked and unchecked.

```
$('span.volume').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#mChatUseSound').toggle(); //this needs to toggle :checked
 });


<span class="volume"></span>
<input type="checkbox" id="mChatUseSound" style="display:none;" /></label>
```

Comment: $('#mChatUseSound').attr("checked", ! $('#mChatUseSound').is(':checked'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, if you use `<label>`, you don't need to write any javascript to toggle checked and unchecked.

```
<label class="volume" for="mChatUseSound">click</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="mChatUseSound" />
```

Just need to write script to handle other logic:

```
$('.volume').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    //More logic
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BNjzt/)

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AHFsj/)

```
$('#mChatUseSound').prop('checked',function(){return !this.checked}).change();
```

As we create a closure, `this` will refer to specific element in set, here '#mChatUseSound'.

Comment: This changes it to checked but it doesn't seem to pick up an action. If I were to take away the `display:none` and clicked the check box the sound would stop. I think it needs a bind of some sort

Comment: So how the 'sound' is supposed to stop, when checkbox state change (becomes unchecked)? Have you already a change event bind to checkbox which make the sound stop? If yes, just trigger change event as in updated answer.

Comment: Ah ok I sussed it, how would I be able to check its checked on page load to do something?

Comment: You could trigger event when setting handler: `$('#mChatUseSound').on('change',function(){
    if(this.checked)
        //enable sound
    else //disable sound
}).change();`  or use the document ready handler or window onload to trigger event. I cannot help you more, i don't know what code you are using